# Phone gets restarted during long running service

Tags: android, android-service

I am using the Galaxy S3 phone. i am running a long service and therefor to see whats going on i save the logs. but after 10-12 hours phone gets restarted and from logs i didn't find any reason for restart.
Is there way to find the reason for restart.

Comment: So if you turn off logs it works? Are you reading into memory and then writing each time, or are you using append?

Comment: Does it happen everytime you leave your service running or just happened once ?

Comment: @NoBugs: i have connected device to pc to save logs.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri:Its not happen every time.

Comment: By 'logs' do you mean logcat?

Comment: @NoBugs:yes i saved all logcat but does't find any reason for reboot. first i think it was due to outofMemory but there was not any exception in logs regarding outofMemory.

Comment: If it just happened ones, may be the phone just ran out of battery power. If it was outofmemory, there would have been an exception.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri:yes you are right there would be some exception and also phone is connected to PC so its continuously charging and also it can be due to overheating as the service is running continuously for long hours.Still trying to find the reason.